# how to open pdf at particular section in new tab/window from code behind in c#

Tags: c#, pdf

I am working on a web application, in which I have a help icon on some screen. All i need to do is when user click on a help icon, a pdf file of help document will open in new tab/window and this pdf should open at a particular section (i.e. should not open from page 1). Please help me out to achieve this.[I want to achieve this in new tab or window. Plz see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ReDy5.jpg)

Here is my code:

```
    protected void registrationHelpIcon_ServerClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string appBaseUrl = Request.Url.Scheme + "://" + Request.Url.Authority + Request.ApplicationPath.TrimEnd('/') + "/";
            string pdfPath = "Temp/xtLytics_security_module.pdf";
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            Byte[] buffer = client.DownloadData(appBaseUrl + pdfPath);
            Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            Response.AddHeader("content-length", buffer.Length.ToString());
            Response.BinaryWrite(buffer);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Log(LogLevel.SystemError, ex);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the same PDF file can behave very differently in different PDF viewers (Acrobat, Preview, Foxit) and native viewers in some browsers (Chrome, Edge) there's no way to do this in any way that will work consistently unless you break the PDF into sections and then just link to the section you need for that help button.